# create a case when a record is created and also create a note and attachment on the case?

Tags: apex, repeat

```
trigger autocreatedocument on Case (after insert) {
list<document> doc = new list<document>();
    for(case docu:trigger.new){
        document D = new document();
        D.Name = 'Techmahindra8';
        D.AuthorId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        D.FolderId = UserInfo.getUserId();
            doc.add(D); 
    }
  if(doc.size()>0)
      insert doc;
}
-------------------------------------------------------
trigger autocreateattachment on Case (after insert) {
list<attachment> atta = new list<attachment>();
    for(case ats:trigger.new){
        string pdfcontent = 'attachment';
Attachment attach=new Attachment();
      attach.Name=ats +'.pdf';
      attach.Body=blob.toPdf(pdfcontent);
      attach.ParentId = '5002800000JvUFG';
      attach.add(atta);
    }
    if(atta.size()>0)
        insert atta;
}
```

Comment: and what is the issue??

Comment: only issue I can see is you are assigning hardcoded caseId to attach.ParentId field. instead it should ats.Id and rest all good I guess

Comment: Please see the guidelines on how to ask a question [ask]

Comment: issues Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Attachment].add(List<Attachment>)

Answer (score 1):

Update your code to

```
trigger autocreateattachment on Case (after insert) {
list<attachment> atta = new list<attachment>();
    for(case ats:trigger.new){
        string pdfcontent = 'attachment';
Attachment attach=new Attachment();
      attach.Name=ats +'.pdf';
      attach.Body=blob.toPdf(pdfcontent);
      attach.ParentId = '5002800000JvUFG'; //never use hardcoded Id if you still want to use then store it in custom setting and then refer from there
      atta.add(attach); // you are doing reverse here
    }
    if(atta.size()>0)
        insert atta;
}
```

Comment: ahh good point. I didn't noticed that. You can also add one more point. the hard coded parent Id.